# Mapping of interceptors in Spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

> I am storing user logging details into database I only want to store to name
>   of the that user currently hitting,datetime,profile etc. I used
>   interceptor for this work  e.g when users hits
>   http://localhost:/projectName/content
>
> using controller content is mapped with the content.jsp  whenever
>   users hit "http://localhost:/projectName/content" its store the every
>   image  link, every css file link to the database that are present in my 
>   content.jsp page.
>
> list of url that storing into the database:

```
 http:/localhost/projectName/content
 http://localhost/projectName/resources/css-wap/bootstrap.css?null
 http://localhost/projectName/resources/css-wap/hover.css?null
 http://localhost/projectName/resources/css-wap/style.css?null
 http://localhost/projectName/resources/img-wap/Game.png?null
```

Code of Interceptor:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
             <bean id="storingWapHits"
                class="packageName.StroringHits">

            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>

</mvc:interceptors>
```

[image: Directory structure of my project]

> I want to store url that only mapped with my jsp folder not resources
>   folder. how can i mapped my interceptor so that its only store browser
>   url that users hit e.g

```
http:/localhost/projectName/content
http:/localhost/projectName/content1
http:/localhost/projectName/content2
```

> i dont want to store

```
http://localhost/projectName/resources/css-wap/bootstrap.css?null
     http://localhost/projectName/resources/css-wap/hover.css?null
     http://localhost/projectName/resources/css-wap/style.css?null
     http://localhost/projectName/resources/img-wap/Game.png?null
```

> this kind of url into my database

Comment: I suggest a read of [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors)... It does what you configured it to do, map to all URLs.

Comment: @ M. Deinum thank you  sir....for solving my problem